# Grails one-to-many using two domains on a single form

Tags: grails

I am new to Grails & Groovy. I am trying to create a single form from two domain classes, but it is not updating both domains.

1) My domain classes are: a)

```
 class Alacat { String email String name Date startdate = new Date() Date   
 enddate = new Date() String starttime String endtime boolean roadclose

static  belongsTo  =  [user :  User]

String  toString()  { return  "User of $name  (id:  $id)" }
String  getDisplayString()  { return  name }

static constraints = {
    email  email:  true,  blank: false
    name blank:  false
    startdate blank:  false
    enddate  blank:  false
    starttime nullable:  true
    endtime   nullable:  true
    roadclose     blank:  false

    alertuser nullable:  false
 }

}
```

(b)

```
class User {
   String  loginId

   Set alerts=[]
   static  hasMany  =  [ alerts :  Alacat ]

   static constraints = {
    loginId  size:  3..20,  blank:  false
   }
}
```

2) My Controller (UserController) logic is:

```
def createalert()  {
   if (request.method == "POST")  {

  def user  =  new User(params) 

  if  (user.validate()) {
     user.save()
     flash.message  = "Successfully Created User"
     redirect(uri : '/User/createalert')

  } else {
     flash.message  =  "Error Creating User"

     return [ user : user]   
      }   
   }    
}
```

3) createalert.gsp view class:

```
<g:form  action="createalert">
  <fieldset class="form">
    <div class="fieldcontain required">
        <label for="loginId">Login ID</label>
        <g:textField name="loginId" value="${user?.loginId}"/>
    </div>

    <div class="fieldcontain required">
        <label for="alerts.email"> Email address:</label>
         <g:textField name="alerts.email"
            value="${user?.alerts?.email}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldcontain required">
        <label for="alerts.name">Name & Title:</label>
        <g:textField name="alerts.name"
            value="${user?.alerts?.name}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldcontain required">
        <label for="alerts.startdate">Start Date Notice:</label>
          <g:datePicker  name="alerts.startdate" value="${new Date()  
         }"                            precision="day" />
    </div>
    <div class="fieldcontain required">
        <label for="alerts.enddate">End Date Notice:</label>
        <g:datePicker  name="alerts.enddate" value="${new Date() }" 
              precision="day" />
    </div>
    <div class="fieldcontain required">
        <label for="alerts.starttime">(optional) St Time:</label>
        <g:textField name="alerts.starttime"
            value="${user?.alerts?.starttime}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldcontain required">
        <label for="alerts.endtime">(optional) E-Time:</label>
        <g:textField name="alerts.endtime"
            value="${user?.alerts?.endtime}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldcontain required">
        <label for="roadclose">closed 24-hours?</label>
        <g:radioGroup name="roadclose"
          labels = "[ 'Yes', 'No']"
          values="[ 'Y', 'N' ]"
          value = "Y">
          ${it.label} ${it.radio}
        </g:radioGroup>
    </div>

</fieldset>
<fieldset class="buttons">
    <g:submitButton name="createalert" value="Create Alert"/>
    <g:link action="createalert">Back to Create  Information </g:link>
</fieldset>
```

Note: My problem is that only the User domain (User - loginId) info is being created while Alacat does not have anything. I want attributes from both domains (User & Alacat) to be created from using the createalert form. I did not get any error while running it.

Answer (score 0):

The `params` Map probably looks something like this:

```
[
    loginId: 'something',
    alerts: [
        email: 'blah',
        name: 'blah blah',
        ...
    ]
]
```

So the User object is being instantiated like this:

```
def user = new User(loginId: 'something', alerts: alerts)
```

`User.alerts` is a Set, not a Map. Besides, I believe you need to call `instance.addTo*()` to add to a hasMany Collection. Try this instead:

```
def user  =  new User(params) 

user.addToAlerts new Alacat(params.alerts)
...
```

And it would be cleaner to create a *user* param

```
<g:textField name="user.loginId" value="${user?.loginId}"/>
```

and then do this:

```
def user = new User(params.user)
```

Stan's reply:
Emmanuel Rosa, 
      Thanks a lot for your help. However, I got this new error message "Property [loginId] of class [class alerts.User] cannot be null".  Here is my controller code:
class UserController {
    static scaffold = true

```
def createalert()  {
    if (request.method == "POST")  {
       def User user  =  new User(params)
       if  (user.validate()) {
           user.addToAlerts  new Alacat(params.alerts)
           user.save()
           flash.message  = "Successfully Created User"
       } else {
           flash.message  =  "Error Creating User"
               }   
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: Emmanuel Rosa,  thanks a lot for your help. However, I got this error message "Property [loginId] of class [class edu.psu.opp.alerts.User] cannot be null".

Comment: Ok, please go ahead an *add* your updated code to your question.

Comment: Emmanuel Rosa,  thanks a lot for your help. However, I got this error message "Property [loginId] of class [class edu.psu.opp.alerts.User] cannot be null".  Here is my controller code:    class UserController {
    static scaffold = true
 
 def createalert()  {
  if (request.method == "POST")  {
     def User user  =  new User(params)
     if  (user.validate()) {
      user.addToAlerts  new Alacat(params.alerts)
      user.save()
      flash.message  = "Successfully Created User"
     } else {
      flash.message  =  "Error Creating User"
       }   
  }  
 }  
}

Comment: What does your loginId `<g:textField>` look like?

Comment: Emmanuel, I am trying to run a test unit on my application and I got the error below. Perhaps, I did not set it properly. It is on the same domains.

Comment: Here is the error:  "Failure:  Get an user given their   
 id(com.grailsinaction.UserControllerSpec)

 |  groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: user for class: 
 com.grailsinaction.UserControllerSpec
 at com.grailsinaction.UserControllerSpec.Get an user given their    
 id(UserControllerSpec.groovy:20)
 | Completed 1 unit test, 1 failed in 0m 4s
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in /Users/stan/target/test-reports
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error

Comment: I need to see the UserControllerSpec source code. Get with me on Google Plus/Hangouts (https://plus.google.com/109886199751744223967/posts) .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this:

```
 <div class="fieldcontain required">
           <label for="loginId">Login ID</label>
           <g:textField name="user.loginId" value="${user?.loginId}"/>
 </div>
```

Also, I changed the User Domain constraints as shown below (i.e. from loginId    blank: false to loginId nullable:true) and it was write null on the login_Id field of User table.

```
class User {
    String  loginId
static constraints = {
    loginId  nullable:true
  }
```

}

Thanks a lot for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

The loginId field is null because the UserController info should be new User(params.user) instead of new User(params). I mean the problem is on my UserController.

Thanks a lot for Emmanuel your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ah! I was just about to tell you that. Great, I'm glad you got it working :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help.